# Change type of property in derived class typescript

Tags: typescript

I have class User and class UserCreateDto extends from User class. I want change type of author property from User to string. But I get an error cannot assign another type to author property. please give me solution. thank. This is my code.

```
   export class Post {
    
      author: User;
    
      title: string;
    
      slug: string;
    
      description: string;
    
      content: string;
    }

    

export class CreatePostDto extends Post {
  author: string;
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. But it doesn't seem right to have `CreatePostDto` claim to be a `Post` when its `author` property has a different type - that breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle, as if you pass it where a `Post` is expected, the recipient will try to access `thing.author.userProperty` and get an unpleasant surprise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.